# Hide imported inkscape pdf in TeXstudio structure view

Tags: texstudio

TeXstudio structure view is great for jumping between items but \import{}{.pdf_tex} adds additional subitems that mess up the structure view and hierarchy.

Is there a way in TeXstudio to hide imported Inkscape-PDFs from the structure view?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to explicitly exclude contents from the structure view. However, you can trick TeXstudio to not recognize the import by defining a new command

```
\newcommand{\imgimport}[2]{\import{#1}{#2}}
```

Then, TeXstudio will not recognize `\imgimport{}{.pdf_tex}` as import.